# SlideDown JQuery

Tags: jquery, button, slidedown

I installed a jQuery script "slideDown", everything works normally but I would like my div disappear when I click outside or when I click on another button. can you help me please ?

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $( "button1" ).click(function() {
          $( "#divacacher1" ).toggle( "slow" );
        });
        $( "button2" ).click(function() {
          $( "#divacacher2" ).toggle( "slow" );
        }); 
        ...
</script>
```

My HTML:

```
<button1>EN SAVOIR PLUS</button1>                                   
<div id="divacacher1" style="display: none;">
   <div class="blockRight">
    ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $( "button1" ).click(function() {
      $( "#divacacher1" ).toggle( "slow" );
      $('body').click(function() {
         $('#divacher1').toggle();
      });

    });
```

Comment: hi, nothing changes. it's like before.
have you another idea?

Comment: ty christopher shaw !